# cannot copy a Jquery object into a Jquery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am trying to insert a JQuery object inside another by doing the following:

```
var htmlCode = $("<div id='"+data.layoutDescriptions[i].id+"'></div");          
if(data.contentRef == "RecursiveContactSubForm"){
        if(htmlArray[2]){
            alert("in here");
        htmlCode.append(htmlArray[2]);
        }
        else{
            alert("in here2");
            var tmp = htmlCode;
            htmlCode.append(tmp);
        }
    }
```

I don't understand why this doesn't work.

any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: @Pekka "content DOM element, HTML string, **or jQuery object** to insert at the end of each element in the set of matched elements."

Comment: @Anthony oops! Maybe I should learn to read.

Comment: The jQuery API docs state that `append` can accept a jQuery object

Comment: When you say "this doesn't work", what do you mean?  Are you getting an error?  Can you be more specific, please?

Comment: Sagar, you might be having trouble because you forgot to close your `div` properly on line 1.

Comment: Hi, please provide also HTML code and what do you mean by does not work? It does nothing? Is there some error? It does something different?

Comment: it says it the api you can use a Jquery object:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming your error is here:

```
var tmp = htmlCode;
htmlCode.append(tmp);
```

This assignment will not create a copy of `htmlCode`, it will create a new reference to it. `tmp` and `htmlCode` represent the same object, so attempting to append an object to itself will fail.

You can use the `clone` function:

```
var tmp = htmlCode.clone(true);
htmlCode.append(tmp);
```

Passing `true` to `clone` will copy any events and data attached to the object into the new object as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
var tmp = htmlCode[0].outerHTML;
htmlCode.append(tmp);
```

While this (I hope) answers your question, it does not address a few issues, in particular, you are pushing an element with the same id as its container, which should really be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

Well, possible things you can do (because your code logic seems good):

**(1)** Check the returning values to make sure if this is what you expect.

```
console.log(htmlCode);
console.log(data.contentRef);
console.log(htmlArray[2]);
console.log(tmp);
```

**(2)** Check the browser console and look for another kind of error (maybe you have a syntax error in some other javascript code).

**(3)** A possible error could be at the assignment of `tmp` variable part, the correct way is using `clone()`:

```
var tmp = htmlCode.clone(true);
```

---

Just to know, the idea of your code is working fine, you can test the following and make sure:

**e.g:**

**Live Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/FYC7L/

```
var htmlArray = new Array("<div id='newElement_1'>Element 1</div>", "<div id='newElement_2'>Element 2</div>", "<div id='newElement_3'>Element 3</div>");

var htmlCode = $("<div id='test'>Test</div>");          

if(htmlArray[2]){
    htmlCode.append(htmlArray[2]);
}

console.log(htmlCode);
```

​As you can see this is working, so there is something (maybe wrong) with your returning values as I wrote in the first part of my post or maybe with `tmp` variable.

**The above example will output:**

[image]

Hope this helps :-)